# matplotlib pyplot UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, x11

I have some problems related to plt.show() and I would describe the problem and what I tried.

**#Problem**

I am using python and plt.show() and those worked well until 4 hours before.

However, when I do plot something, suddenly

```
directory/plots/distance.py:119: UserWarning: Matplotlib is currently using agg, which is a non-GUI backend, so cannot show the figure.
  plt.show()
```

showed at the bottom of terminal.

**#Trial 1**

I searched google and add `import matplotlib, matplotlib.use('TkAgg'), import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` for obspy-plot Data.seed.

This worked for my coworker who shared server and had the same problem with me.

But it did not work for me but showed `site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 275, in switch_backend raise ImportError( ImportError: Cannot load backend 'TkAgg' which requires the 'tk' interactive framework, as 'headless' is currently running`.

So I changed 'TkAgg' to 'Agg' but there was no error but also no plots.

**#Trial2**

I try to `conda install -c conda-forge python3-tk` and `conda install -c anaconda tk` (I cannot use pip or sudo).

But nothing changed related to the 'TkAgg' error.

**#Trial3**

I add `import tkinter` before 'TkAgg'part but nothing changed.

**#So..**

I think the matplotlib in my anaconda has something wrong but have no idea how to fix it.

(I still cannot understand why this problem occurs suddenly..)

Could you please let me know how to solve this problem?

Comment: You have left off the relevant info that you are probably logging on to a remote machine.  It simply seems that your x11 display connection timed out due to inactivity

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much!